# Нарисовать след от фигуры

Tags: swing, java, graphics

Идея очень проста: по єкрану двигается квадрат и от него должен оставаться след. Думал, что єто будет проще простого, но fillRect оказался круче, чем я думал и квадрат перемещается без следа. Есть идеи?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно при каждом перемещении фигуры рисовать новую( или несколько - если перемещается на несколько пикселей. Можно засунуть перемещение в главный таймер программы

Comment: Сам себе отвечает,чтобы накрутить балы?))

Comment: Действительно, как две капли воды.

Comment: Сори, не с того аккаунта зашел(

Comment: Сам понял что надо сделать. А отвечать-как рыбы!!!